# How do i setup zeromq with django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, python-2.7, zeromq

I am working on zeromq PUB/SUB and I setuped zeromq PUB on django.

This is my code that i use for setting up zeromq

```
from gevent_zeromq import zmq
```

i am using gevent_zeromq library

```
@api_view(['POST','GET'])
def NOTIFICATION(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_to_response('notifications.html',context)
if request.method == 'POST':
    message_json = json.dumps(request.data)
    message_load = json.loads(message_json)
    message = {message_load['msg']}
    ctx = zmq.Context()
    publisher = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
    publisher.bind("tcp://*:5566")
    time.sleep(1)
    while True:
        publisher.send_multipart("message:%s" % str(message))
        time.sleep(1)
    publisher.close()
    ctx.term() 
return Response('',status=200)
```

I am using ajax/jquery for data coming throgh web.

This code is working, but when I send another message from frontend it is giving me error:

```
 File "/home/admin/dx_man/dx_man/views.py", line 42, in NOTIFICATION
    publisher.bind("tcp://*:5566")
    File "socket.pyx", line 447, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.bind (zmq/core/socket.c:4312)
    ZMQError: Address already in use
```

How can I do it with using ajax, django.zeromq.

I want to make only publisher, subscriber will be seperate so once publisher will publish the message later on subscriber will be handle it, but here I am facing issue.

Can anyone give me best solution for it so that I can handle all message from web interface and I also want to store messages into the database, that I will handle once message will be publish.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're spinning up the ZMQ context and socket for each request, if anything prevents the socket and context from terminating and releasing the port before your next message then that will cause an issue when you try to bind on the same port again.

You have a couple of options:

- Create the context and socket once, and re-use them for each request (this would be my preferred approach, so long as the Python process is persistent across calls, which it may not be)
- remove the `time.sleep(1)` calls, as they might be causing the process to take too long to close
- set ZMQ_LINGER to zero before you close, which will force it to close even if there are still messages waiting... which could mean some messages don't get sent, if they are taking too long.
- If you absolutely need to spin up your context and socket each time to send your message, and they'll be coming fast enough that you can't break the last one down before the next one comes in, then you should be `connect()`-ing on your PUB socket and `bind()`-ing on your SUB socket.

This is a classic case where your PUB socket is temporary and your SUB socket is reliable, so your SUB socket should be your "server" and `bind()`.

Comment: i did it while True:
            publisher.send("message:%s" % str(message))
            #time.sleep(1)
            publisher.close()

Comment: message sending work  but i don't know why i am geting this error   File "socket.pyx", line 518, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.send (zmq/core/socket.c:4609)
  File "socket.pyx", line 84, in zmq.core.socket._check_closed (zmq/core/socket.c:1106)
ZMQError: Operation not supported

Comment: If you're getting a new error, it's best to open a new question.